# Obtener petición GET en una etiqueta <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

¿Cómo puedo obtener la petición `GET` de una etiqueta `<a>`? es decir, sí tengo:

```
<a href="ejemplo1" > Ejemplo #1</a>
<a href="ejemplo2" > Ejemplo #2</a>
<a href="ejemplo3" > Ejemplo #3</a>
```

Dicho `href` mostrarlo por consola, algo tipo que cada vez que de click en un enlace, muestre su `href` correspondiente:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //aqui debería ir el codigo
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La url completa con `event.target.href`

```js
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(e.target.href);

});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <a href="ejemplo3" > Ejemplo #3</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```js
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(href);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="ejemplo1" > Ejemplo #1</a>

<a href="ejemplo2" > Ejemplo #2</a>

<a href="ejemplo3" > Ejemplo #3</a>
```